# Add htmlentities and/or shortcode into data-attributes

Tags: plugins, shortcode, html5

I realize this is crazy but, I built up a filtered gallery with quicksand and it pulls in a larger image, title and description when you click the smaller image it shows the data-img in a larger form. Below is the code that is currently working...

```
<img src="<?php echo $large_image ?>" data-img="<?php echo $large_image ?>"
 data-title="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>" 
 data-description="<?php the_content();?>" alt="" class="superbox-img" />
```

My client came back and asked if they could change the larger images that is begin pulled from the data-img attribute from static images to galleries... So I installed the Advanced Custom Fields plugin and added a WYSIWYG editor, for a shortcode field, in the portfolio posts (custom page type). Which I would like to import a royal slider(http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/) short code into. I've since changed the code from above to the following...

```
<img src="<?php echo $large_image ?>" 
data-img="<?php htmlentities(the_field('portfolio_galleries')); ?>" 
data-title="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>" 
data-description="<?php the_content();?>" alt="" class="superbox-img" />
```

Which is throwing an error and spitting out the following HTML...

```
<img src="http://localhost:8888/BVH/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/St-Francis-Assisi-Interior-6-.jpg" 
data-img="<div id="new-royalslider-6" class="royalSlider new-royalslider-6 rsMinW rs-simple-vertical" 
style="width:100%; height:500;">
<div class="rsContent">

<a class="rsImg" href="http://localhost:8888/BVH/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/test1-1024x437.png">test1</a>
<div class="rsTmb">test1</div>

</div><div class="rsContent">

<a class="rsImg" href="http://localhost:8888/BVH/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/test2-1024x437.png">test2</a>
<div class="rsTmb">test2</div></div>

<div class="rsContent">
<a class="rsImg" href="http://localhost:8888/BVH/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/test3-1024x437.png">test3</a>
<div class="rsTmb">test3</div></div></div>" 

data-title="Doane" data-description="<p>testing1234</p>" 
alt="" class="superbox-img" />
```

Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way but the initial gallery worked great and I'm wondering how to go about accomplishing this problem any help would be great as I know this is probably a lost cause the way I'm currently trying to accomplish this. :-/

Thanks in advanced.

UPDATE:

```
data-img="&lt;div id=&quot;new-royalslider-6&quot; 
class=&quot;royalSlider new-royalslider-6 rsMinW rs-simple-vertical&quot;  
style=&quot;width:100%; height:500;&quot;&gt;&lt;div 
class=&quot;rsContent&quot;&gt; &lt;a 
class=&quot;rsImg&quot; href=&quot;localhost:8888/BVH/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/…; &lt;div`
```

Comment: You really need to provide more information here. Are we talking about [jQuery Quicksand](http://razorjack.net/quicksand/)? What kind of content are you using it for ? What script are you using to pull the larger image from the data attribute? D Do you want to use quicksand in combination with the royal slider? How exactly? What would happen if the user would click on the quicksand item? Would it display a modal box or show inline somewhere in the page?

Comment: Yes, I apologize. I'm using jQuery Quicksand for the filtering. I'm using images from my "featured image" that is getting filtered and I show a title on hover. I"m using Superbox to show the larger images - http://toddmotto.com/labs/superbox/ - I'd like to use the quicksand and as stated before. use the data-img for the royal slider. Here is a link to what I have now - http://bvh.delineamultimedia.com/?page_id=2 - When you click the image there is a dropdown, I want to keep the featured image and replace the image after the click by the title and desc with the slider. I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the additional information. I looked at your code and it becomes much clearer now what you try to accomplish. I will edit my answer below.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your help! I don't believe htmlentities is the way to go but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

`the_field` echoes the output while `htmlentities()` expects the value to be returned. Try `get_field` instead:

```
data-img="<?php echo htmlentities(get_field('portfolio_galleries')); ?>"
```

UPDATE:

Instead of adding this huge chunk of html for the slider to the data-attribute just add it *after* your image:

```
<img src="<?php echo $large_image ?>"  
data-title="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>" 
data-description="<?php the_content();?>" alt="<?php echo get_the_title(); // be nice ?>" class="superbox-img" />
the_field('portfolio_galleries');
```

and hide it with your css:

```
.portfolio-item .royalSlider { display: none; }
```

Now load the html into your superbox container when the user clicks on the item by editing this into your **superbox.js** around line 36:

```
superbox.find('.royalSlider').remove(); // remove the slider from previous events
var imgData = currentimg.data();
var sliderData = currentimg.next('.royalSlider'); // grab the slider html that we want to insert

superboximg.attr('src', imgData.img); 

    if (sliderData) { // show the slider if there is one
        superbox.clone().append(sliderData); // clone the element so we don't loose it for the next time the user clicks
    } else { // if there is no slider proceed as before
        if (imgData.title) {
            superbox.append('<h3 class="title">' + imgData.title + '</h3>');
        }
        if (imgData.description) {
            superbox.append('<div class="description">' + imgData.description + '</div>');
        }
    }
```

There are prettier ways to do this like echoing the urls of the slider to the `<img />` attributes and then generating the slider html by looping through these urls but for now this should work.

Comment: Could you please edit this into your original answer? I can't read anything from this ;)

Comment: That certainly fixed the error it was throwing but I'm still not seeing the gallery probably because the html output is the following after that fix... Anyway to remove the "&quot;"? above is the code in the original question where it says "UPDATE" Sorry about that.

Comment: I think I need to re-think the solution. This isn't currently working at all.

Comment: did you try my updated answer?

Comment: Trying it now. This is exactly what I was wanting to do!!! Will let you know once I've finished if it works properly. Thank you soo so much!

Comment: I'm wondering if the Javascript is working right. I've uploaded these changes to my link (http://bvh.delineamultimedia.com/?page_id=2) and as of right now its still not showing but I feel this is a much better route to go. currently trying to troubleshoot this.

Comment: Currently there is no gallery html displayed. How are you building your item list?

Comment: huh, refresh. I'm seeing it in the source code. cache? The gallery is inserted from the royal slider shortcode in the advanced custom field wysiwyg editor on that specific page type.

Comment: I've put a <div class="gallery"> around the gallery hopefully that helps you located it.

Comment: The slider seems to be loaded into the superbox container just fine...?

Comment: Well its working now just fine but, its showing up under each superbox dropdowns not just the one item dropdown.